# How would I select all the rows in a table based on a column where the data is null until the next item

Tags: plsql

I have an SQL database, I have 2 columns that I'm currently trying to go through, One is an ID column, where in this example I have an id of "TST" for testing, and then all following rows will be null until a new id is declared, and so on. Each null ID is essentially a child of the first ID.

The second column is a code, which in this case for the row TST the code would be 001. This increases by the same value for each new child of a child. The row I'm trying to select has a code of 001001001001001. I know the code will be 15 characters long, but if I try to select based on the ID, I dont find the data as the ID of the row I'm looking for is (null).

What PL/SQL statement would I use to retrieve all the rows until the next ID, so that I can then select the code based off of the string length? I am unable to change the database.

So far I have tried

```
SELECT code
FROM table
WHERE ID='TST' AND LENGTH(code)=15
```

this obviously didn't work. But I cant find a solution on google for this problem

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you can't do it with current way of storing data. In a relational database, rows aren't sorted in any particular way so if you had e.g.

```
TST 001
    001001
OSC 001
    001001
```

you can't tell which ID is related to which 001001 code. It might be obvious when you look at it written on a paper, but in a table - no way.

A simple solution is to store ID for **every** row; then your query would work.